# Javascript, make random_generated image as background

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

## **What I have**

I have a HTML  & javascript code : The javascript generate a `random_number` and use it as indexing on the array of images.Then,the script add the selected picture to the `<img>` tag of html code.
It's works very well.

## **What I need**

I want to make the  tags as background_image(display texts in it,buttons and more). Is there any way to do it? /searched lot of in google and there's no excellent result/.

Thank you for help. :(

```js
window.onload = function() {
var cGamePic = new Array("http://advsys.net/ken/voxlap/voxlap_lib.jpg","http://advsys.net/ken/voxlap/cave.png");
var cGameName = new Array("Voxlap1", "Voxlap2");
var randomItemContainer1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cGamePic.length); //container1

var randomItemContainer2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cGamePic.length); //container2

var comp1GameTitle = document.querySelector("#container1 h1"); //Heading from main container
var comp1GameImage = document.querySelector("#container1 img"); //Image from main container


var comp2GameTitle = document.querySelector("#container2 h1"); //Heading from main container
var comp2GameImage = document.querySelector("#container2 img"); //Image from main container


comp1GameTitle.innerHTML = cGameName[randomItemContainer1]; //Random Title
comp1GameImage.src = cGamePic[randomItemContainer1]; //Random image 



comp2GameTitle.innerHTML = cGameName[randomItemContainer2]; //Random Title
comp2GameImage.src = cGamePic[randomItemContainer2]; //Random image
};
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
 <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
 <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
        <title>Random_page</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="rnd.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
 <!--width:45%; margin: 10px;-->
        <div id="container1" style="float:left; width:45%; margin: 10px;">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <img src="" width='100%' height='100%' />
        </div>
        <div id="container2" style="float:left; width:45%; margin: 10px;">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <img src="" width='100%' height='100%' />
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean you want to make the tags as background_image? Avoid posting your entire code - just post the part that is pertinent to the question.

Comment: You know ,you can do it in CSS with background:url(...) attribute that sets the image to the entire-screen /and your site will run on this background/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to apply those random images as a background, it will be set as a background image of a `div` and not an `img`, so replace your `img` with a `div` and instead of writing:

```
comp1GameImage.src = cGamePic[randomItemContainer1];
```

You will need to write:

```
comp1GameImage.style.backgroundImage = "url('"+ cGamePic[randomItemContainer1]+"')";
```

Where `comp1GameÎmage` is your `div`.

**Here's your updated Snippet:**

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var cGamePic = new Array("http://advsys.net/ken/voxlap/voxlap_lib.jpg", "http://advsys.net/ken/voxlap/cave.png");
  var cGameName = new Array("Voxlap1", "Voxlap2");
  var randomItemContainer1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cGamePic.length); //container1

  var randomItemContainer2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cGamePic.length); //container2

  var comp1GameTitle = document.querySelector("#container1 h1"); //Heading from main container
  var comp1GameImage = document.querySelector("#container1"); //Image from main container


  var comp2GameTitle = document.querySelector("#container2 h1"); //Heading from main container
  var comp2GameImage = document.querySelector("#container2"); //Image from main container


  comp1GameTitle.innerHTML = cGameName[randomItemContainer1]; //Random Title
  comp1GameImage.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + cGamePic[randomItemContainer1] + "')";
  //cGamePic[randomItemContainer1]; //Random image 



  comp2GameTitle.innerHTML = cGameName[randomItemContainer2]; //Random Title
  comp2GameImage.style.backgroundImage = "url('" + cGamePic[randomItemContainer2] + "')";
  //cGamePic[randomItemContainer2]; //Random image
};
```

```css
#container1,
#container2 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 45%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
  <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">
  <title>Random_page</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="rnd.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <!--width:45%; margin: 10px;-->
  <div id="container1">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="container2">
    <h1>Title</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**EDIT:**

To make the two divs split the page into two frames, give them these styles:

```
#container1, #container2{
     display:inline-block;
     width:45%;
     height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. I want to do it as => 2 container, that seperate the screen to 2 side horizontally. Example => [ IMAGE | IMAGE ].

Comment: Take a look at my **EDIT**.

Comment: Uh, you have done with an amazing job. But I still don't understand how it's re-sized the two container/image. Can you show an example how to make the two image to fit 50/50 of the screen horizontally? (like, I want to use the entire screen, but force the browser to make the page un-scrollable horizontally-vertically).

Comment: Uh, yes. It's solved my problem. I've almost done with my project. But it's needs a big big update to be finally done. Thank you, I forgot to mark it.

Comment: Great, glad it helps ;)

Answer (score 1):

You could make **images** look like  background (NOT in background) by **overlapping** `H1` on `IMG` using CSS :

```
[id*=container] {
    position:relative; /*--container is relative*/
                     
}

 h1 {
    position:absolute; /*Image title is absolute*/
    top:30px;
    left:30px;
}
```

---

## DEMO :

```js
window.onload = function() {
var cGamePic = new Array("http://advsys.net/ken/voxlap/voxlap_lib.jpg","http://advsys.net/ken/voxlap/cave.png");
var cGameName = new Array("Voxlap1", "Voxlap2");
var randomItemContainer1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cGamePic.length); //container1

var randomItemContainer2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cGamePic.length); //container2

var comp1GameTitle = document.querySelector("#container1 h1"); //Heading from main container
var comp1GameImage = document.querySelector("#container1 img"); //Image from main container


var comp2GameTitle = document.querySelector("#container2 h1"); //Heading from main container
var comp2GameImage = document.querySelector("#container2 img"); //Image from main container


comp1GameTitle.innerHTML = cGameName[randomItemContainer1]; //Random Title
comp1GameImage.src = cGamePic[randomItemContainer1]; //Random image 



comp2GameTitle.innerHTML = cGameName[randomItemContainer2]; //Random Title
comp2GameImage.src = cGamePic[randomItemContainer2]; //Random image
};
```

```css
[id*=container] {
    position:relative; 
                     
}

 h1 {
    position:absolute;
    top:30px;
    left:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--width:45%; margin: 10px;-->
        <div id="container1" style="float:left; width:45%; margin: 10px;">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <img src="" width='100%' height='100%' />
        </div>
        <div id="container2" style="float:left; width:45%; margin: 10px;">
            <h1>Title</h1>
            <img src="" width='100%' height='100%' />
        </div>
```